# RedirectMatch issues with Regular Expression

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am having an issue with  WordPress creating lots of urls that don't exist, so was thinking of putting in a few redirectmatch 301 to sort the problem out.

so the url I have is http://www.website.com/section/page/32/?cat=41

Where the 32 is the page number and does exist but not sure where the ?cat=41 comes from. I want to redirect anything that come up with this to the page its on, is this possible or will it get into a redirect loop?

I thought that using a regular expression the following would work.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/section/page/(.*)/?cat=(.*)$ /section/page/
```

Comment: You should figure out where the problem actually exists, before using redirect/rewrite rules. There's obviously something in your template/functions/theme/a plugin that's causing the query string to be appended to your URL.

Comment: rnevius Very valid point, thank you!